# docker notary : tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Tags: docker

I receive this error when I try to push and sign image in a private registry. Steps to reproduce:

1. Deploy registry:

   ```
   $ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
   ```
2. Tag the image:

   ```
   $ docker tag hello-world localhost:5000/hello-world:latest
   ```
3. Enable content trust:

   ```
   $ export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
   ```
4. Push on registry:

   ```
   $ docker push localhost:5000/hello-world:latest
   => The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/hello-world]
   a02596fdd012: Pushed 
   latest: digest: sha256:a18ed77532f6d6781500db650194e0f9396ba5f05f8b50d4046b294ae5f83aa4 size: 524
   Signing and pushing trust metadata
   tls: oversized record received with length 20527
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your registry is not accepting https connections since it is on http. forget about the `DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST` and add your registry as an insecure registry using `--insecure-registry` daemon option in your docker daemon config and then restart docker afterwards

Comment: Thank you very much but I already tried this and it's not working for me.

Comment: What is your os? Can I see your docker config file contents?

Comment: I am working with Ubuntu 16.04. /etc/default/docker: ... # Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --insecure-registry https://notary.docker.io/v2 --insecure-registry localhost:5000"

Comment: it is not your docker configuration file. you are using systemd for ubuntu 16.04 so the configuration file be in your systemd service config directory . check this reference https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this only when I set up the content trust server to point to running notary server.

> export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST_SERVER=https://localhost:4443

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using a proxy to pull down the images, take a look at proxy configuration. In particular, make sure https proxy URL does not contain "https" string, for example:

```
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.url:8080/" => Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.url:8080/"
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717390/ubuntu-docker-proxyconnect-tcp-tls-oversized-record-received-with-length-20) for a more complete explanation