# Ubuntu, Docker - proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tcp, daemon, tls1.2

I am running a docker binary I built (following [this](http://oyvindsk.com/writing/docker-build-from-source)) and when I do a `docker pull`, I get this error.

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

I have set the proxy as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/), and the `pull` works fine with the default daemon and the same proxy settings. Changing DNS to 8.8.8.8 doesn't seem to help.

```
ping registry-1.docker.io
```

results in 100% packet loss.

`docker info` gives this

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: dev
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa (expected: fec3683)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-43-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.853GiB
Name: bhavana-docker
ID: UKZT:U4LR:PBOV:GLXP:XXUP:MZ74:WXWL:3RT7:MOG5:YGMC:HAFI:7PYM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: <suppressed>
HTTPS Proxy: <suppressed>
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 registry-1.docker.io
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

What is the fix for this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What is your Docker version?

With Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4, it was working for me, but after `yum update` to get Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825, I had the same problem.

Could you please check your /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf ? I think you have configured like this :

```
HTTPS_PROXY=https://user:pwd@proxy:port
```

But now, try to configure HTTPS_PROXY with http protocol instead of https protocol :

```
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:pwd@proxy:port
```